# PHP gallery description only showing first letter

Tags: php

I was following the 2nd part of this tutorial where it shows pictures with descriptions under them. http://www.devtek.org/tutorials/image_gallery.php

I ran into a issue where the description I put in the .txt file only will only display the first letter.  I'm assuming the array is only reading the first letter, and I can change it to read the 2nd,3rd, and 4th letters but not everything at once.  The code is the same on the webpage exactly.

And also here is the live site I'm playing around with

www.digifind-it.com/test/script.php

Comment: My crystal ball seems to be broken, please add some code into your question, especially te snippet that builds the txt file

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please ask your question directly, don't expect anyone to go read the tutorial you're following and try to figure out where you are in.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

`echo '<td align="center"><a href="' . $images . $big . $file . '"><img src="' . $images . $file . '" /></a><br />' . $description[$file][0] . '</td>';`

to

`echo '<td align="center"><a href="' . $images . $big . $file . '"><img src="' . $images . $file . '" /></a><br />' . $description[$file]. '</td>';`

Explanation:
You have an array $desription like this

```
Array
(
    [] => 
    [PICT0168.JPG] => Balloon Fiesta!

    [PICT0259.JPG] => Our Halloween Pumpkin

    [PICT0271.JPG] => Converting our garage to a halloween cave

    [PICT0282.JPG] => My little ghoulish helpers

    [PICT0524.JPG] => Ash meets Cinderella on her 7th B-day

    [PICT0633.JPG] => Jayden's first snowday

)
```

So when you use `$description[$file][0]` you are actually calling the first character of the string
To show an example try:

```
$string = "Hello World";
echo $string[0]; // output H
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much, the page is gracious to your quick response!

Comment: @user2125063 next time try to narrow down the problem and provide some code